# ruby delegate enumerize field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having model with enumerize field:

```rb
class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Enumerize

  attr_accessible :field_in_delegate

  enumerize :field_in_delegate,
            in: {option_one: 1, option_two: 2, option_three: 3},
            default: :option_one, predicates: true, scope: true
end
```

I can delegate field_in_delegate when it field is enumerize

```rb
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Enumerize


  attr_accessible :field_in_delegate

  delegate :field_in_delegate, to: :model_b

  has_one :model_b  
end
```

then I can call

> modelA.field_in_delegate

without problem but I can't call

> modelA.option_one?

how can I dry mode access to helpers methods provided by [enumerize gem](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize) through delegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ways to do this:

1. Override `method_missing` on `ModelA` to forward any missing method calls to the delegate

   ```
   class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
     extend Enumerize
     ...
     delegate :field_in_delegate, to: :model_b

     def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
       if field_in_delegate.respond_to?(method)
         field_in_delegate.send(method, *args, &block)
       else
         super
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. Delegate individual methods to `field_in_delegate`:

   ```
   class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
     extend Enumerize
     ...
     delegate :field_in_delegate, :option_one?, :option_two?, to: :model_b
   end
   ```

   With this approach, you can define what delegated per requirement.

Comment: You right. And second option works well for me and more convenience in my scenario.

Comment: I think the first option is really clever but less readable. Thanks for the answer.